# JSX control visibility of title based on elements contained in props

Tags: reactjs, styling

I have a component that has a list that is being displayed and a title.

I know how to do this with two separate props

```
class ListsInBatch extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><div styles={this.props.Visibility}>Lists ready for batch processing</div><div id="listsInBatch">{this.props.Lists}</div></div>)
    };
}
```

however, I want to do it in such a way that visibility would be based on if there are lists in the prop something like:

```
class ListsInBatch extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><div styles="display : { return (this.props.Lists.length > 0 ? "block" : "none")}">Lists ready for batch processing</div> <div id="listsInBatch">{this.props.Lists}</div></div >)
    };
}
```

the latter does not work but should indicte for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work, you can do something like:

```
class ListsInBatch extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={{ display: this.props.Lists.length > 0 ? "block" : "none" }}>
            Lists ready for batch processing
          </div>
          <div id="listsInBatch">{this.props.Lists}</div>
        </div >
      )
  };
}
```

If you are using ES6, I'll highly recommend you to use [object destructuring](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f?gi=8d7b33489f99), you can check how it looks like in the example below:

```
class ListsInBatch extends Component {
  render() {
    const { Lists } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: Lists.length > 0 ? "block" : "none" }}>
          Lists ready for batch processing
        </div>
        <div id="listsInBatch">{Lists}</div>
      </div >
    )
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Style accepts an object, try:

```
class ListsInBatch extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div><div style={{display: this.props.Lists.length > 0 ? "block" : "none"}}>Lists ready for batch processing</div> <div id="listsInBatch">{this.props.Lists}</div></div >)
    };
}
```